# Attempting CodeChef Challenge "ATM" - Getting SIGSEGV runtime error

Tags: c, runtime, segmentation-fault

I have currently just started learning C (as PHP and related languages are more my field), so I thought I'd start off with a challenge.

I decided to go onto CodeChef and try one of their easy practice challenges, but apparently my code gets a SIGSEGV error on runtime.

Could you please check my code to see why I am getting this error, the code runs fine on multiple boxes which I've tried it on (Mac OSX, Linux (CentOS and Ubuntu)).

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef BANK_CHARGE
  #define BANK_CHARGE  0.5
#endif;

int main (int argc, char **argv){
  // if(argc != 3){
  //   printf("Usage: %s [int] [float]\n", argv[0]);
  //   exit(1);
  // }

  int withdraw = atoi(argv[1]);
  float balance = atof(argv[2]);

  if((withdraw % 5) != 0){
    printf("%.2f", balance);
    exit(1);
  }
  if(withdraw > 2000 || withdraw == 0){
    printf("%.2f", balance);
    exit(1);
  }

  float totalWithdraw = (withdraw + BANK_CHARGE);

  if(totalWithdraw >= balance){
    printf("%.2f", balance);
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("%.2f", balance - totalWithdraw);
  return 0;
}
```

The challenge is located here: http://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST

But here is the problem summary:

> All submissions for this problem are available.
>
> Pooja would like to withdraw X $US from an ATM. The cash machine will
>   only accept the transaction if X is a multiple of 5, and Pooja's
>   account balance has enough cash to perform the withdrawal transaction
>   (including bank charges). For each successful withdrawal the bank
>   charges 0.50 $US.
>
> Calculate Pooja's account balance after an attempted transaction.
>   Input
>
> Positive integer 0 < X <= 2000 - the amount of cash which Pooja wishes
>   to withdraw.
>
> Nonnegative number 0<= Y <= 2000 with two digits of precision -
>   Pooja's initial account balance. Output
>
> Output the account balance after the attempted transaction, given as a
>   number with two digits of precision. If there is not enough money in
>   the account to complete the transaction, output the current bank
>   balance. Example - Successful Transaction
>
> Input: 30 120.00
>
> Output:
>   89.50
>
> Example - Incorrect Withdrawal Amount (not multiple of 5)
>
> Input: 42 120.00
>
> Output:
>   120.00
>
> Example - Insufficient Funds
>
> Input: 300 120.00
>
> Output:
>   120.00

Comment: It is not recommended to use the [`atoi()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html) or [`atof()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atof.html) functions, as they provide no error handling, and you get Undefined Behavior in the case of conversion failure.

Comment: The recommended function to use instead of `atoi()` is the [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) function, and instead of `atof()` use the [`strtod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html) function. These functions provide well-defined error handling.

Comment: Ah I did not know that, I was always told to use the ato* functions, but that's good to know, I'll try that and let you know how it works :)

Comment: Error checking is always important. Error handling is nice, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SIGSEGV - segment fault. This implies that a part of your program is actually attempting to read from *or* write to a memory address for which your program has no permission.

Something as simple as running the program with no command arguments may cause this operating system error as there are no guarantees that `argv[1]` or `argv[2]` are valid memory locations you are permitted to read from. More likely the random numbers contained by `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` are almost certainly not valid locations `atoi` or `atof` may read from. Unsure why you commented out the check for valid number of arguments because this would protect your program from committing this sin.

I presume you are running on a Unix-based operating system such as Linux to be getting a SIGSEGV in the first place. Thus I recommend you run your program within GNU debugger (`gdb`) which would also show you the line of code that caused this error. Using a debugger is a *great* learning technique and will have you solving problems before you take them to the wider community. (hint, hint).

Comment: I commented it out to ensure that, that wasn't causing the submission error, but normally I would use that check in there if I was writing it in a real-world example. Okay, so I need to ensure everything is being written/read correctly, I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: Okay I added that check back in and it stopped the SIGSEGV fault, but now I'm getting an NZEC error :/ Thanks again!